# process to load database in django project

Tags: django, python-2.7

what is the correct process to move a django cms_project to the server?

I create the database from my project like this

```
./manage.py dumpdata > resource/ddbb/20160817_db.json
```

I save inside the project in `resource file`

I move the entire project to the server and after that I execute that command

```
python manage.py loaddata resource/ddbb/20160817_db.json
```

But I obtain this error

```
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named djangocms_admin_style
```

any idea how to solvent?

Thanks in advances

Comment: this just means you don't have djangocms_admin_style installed on your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means django cannot find a package named `djangocms_admin_style`. It seems like you are using `django-admin-shortcuts`. In that case you have to make sure that `djangocms_admin_style` and `djangocms_admin_style` to `INSTALLED_APPS` of your `settings.py` after installing djangocms_admin_style with pip`. Use command below to install djangocms_admin_style

```
pip install djangocms_admin_style
```

as per [docs](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-admin-style) `add 'djangocms_admin_style' to your INSTALLED_APPS just before 'django.contrib.admin'`